# Wortfolge: "Selbst wenn die Dreharbeiten schwierig waren, der Film ist ein großer Erfolg."

Tags: subordinate-clause, wortfolge

In der *Übungsgrammatik für die Oberstufe* (Hueber) steht folgender Satz:

> (1) Auch wenn / Selbst wenn die Dreharbeiten schwierig waren, der Film
> **ist** ein großer Erfolg.

Ich habe geglaubt, die Wortfolge mit einem vorangestellten *auch wenn/selbst wenn*-Satz wäre die gleiche wie mit einem *obwohl*-Satz:

> (2) Obwohl die Dreharbeiten schwierig waren, **ist** der Film ein großer
> Erfolg.

Ich habe in der *Grammatik aktiv B2-C1* nachgeschlagen:

> (3) Auch wenn / Selbst wenn ich im letzten Jahr Geld gehabt hätte,
> **hätte** ich keine Weltreise gemacht.

Die Wortfolge sieht hier vertrauter aus.

SOS – ich bin verwirrt-verwirrt-verwirrt – ist die Wortfolge in dem oberen konzessiven Satz (1) tatsächlich korrekt?

---

Eine weitere Frage zum Konjunktionaladverb *dennoch*:

> (4) Ich habe ihn eingeladen, dennoch ist er nicht zu meiner Party
> gekommen.
>
> (5) Ich habe ihn eingeladen, er ist dennoch nicht zu meiner Party
> gekommen.

(Beispielquelle: https://deutschegrammatik20.de/komplexer-satz/ubersicht-satzverbindung/satzverbindung-dennoch/)

In der *Übungsgrammatik für die Oberstufe* finde ich folgende Satzbeispiele:

> (6) Wenn die Dreharbeiten auch noch so schwierig waren, der Film ist
> dennoch ein Erfolg.
>
> (7) Waren die Dreharbeiten auch noch so schwierig, so ist der Film
> dennoch ein Erfolg.

In (4) und (5) haben wir zwei HS; die Wortfolge hier ist absolut nachvollziehbar. Beeinflusst der vorangestellte Konzessivsatz die Wortfolge in (6) etwa nicht? Müsste es nicht heißen:

¿? Wenn die Dreharbeiten auch noch so schwierig waren, ist der Film dennoch ein Erfolg.

Vielen Dank!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nebensätze können syntaktisch desintegriert sein und im Vor-Vorfeld stehen. Ein Beispiel mit *obwohl*:

> Obwohl du das nicht hören willst, das Auto ist defekt und muss in die Werkstatt.

Bei dem obigen Beispiel wird der Konnektor metakommunikativ verwendet: es geht nicht um eine unerwartete Folge (wie bei *obwohl das Auto erst in der Werkstatt war, ist es schon wieder defekt*) sondern eine unerwartete Äußerung (*obwohl du das nicht hören willst, sage ich es dir*). Vielleicht begünstigen manche Verwendungen, manche Bedeutungen die syntaktische Desintegration.

Prinzipiell sollte die Integration (also "normale" Wortstellung) immer möglich sein. Als dritte Möglichkeit existiert die Korrelatvariante mit *so*.

> Wenn die Dreharbeiten auch noch so schwierig waren, ist der Film dennoch ein Erfolg.
>
> Wenn die Dreharbeiten auch noch so schwierig waren, der Film ist dennoch ein Erfolg.
>
> Wenn die Dreharbeiten auch noch so schwierig waren, so ist der Film dennoch ein Erfolg.

Siehe [Desintegration von Subjunktorphrasen](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/1602).

Comment: Ich frage mich, wie man den Titel der Frage so verändern könnte, dass die Frage von Leuten gefunden wird, die das gleiche Phänomen suchen, aber einen anderen Beispielsatz haben. Hast du vielleicht eine gute Idee?

Comment: Nebensatz vor Hauptsatz? Nebensatz + Subjekt + finites Verb?

Comment: das paradebeispiel sind weil-Sätze, weil die verstoßen gegen Lehrmeinung. Ist das nicht das gleiche, wie auch immer man es nennt?

Answer (score -2):

> Auch wenn / Selbst wenn die Dreharbeiten schwierig waren, der Film ist ein großer Erfolg.

Im Vergleich mit *Trotzdem*, das offenbar als mit Artikel fusioniert betrachtet wird (obwohl hinreichend oft *trotz'em* zu hören sein dürfte; übrigens auch mundartlich "wie wenn'ze träumst"), muss die *Auch wenn ...* Floskel, bzw. hier "Selbst wenn die ...", als ein wenngleich beugbares wohl einziges Wort begriffen werden, bzw. im Zweifelsfall als einheitliche Phrase. Die Betonug liegt prototypischer Weise auf *wenn*, ja wenn ein Konditionalsatz gemeint ist (3), wobei die schwere Silbe *selbst* den Akzent vielleicht verschluckt oder doch noch verstärkt. Auch *Obwohl* erscheint als Jambus (2). In der idiomatischen Wendung wird jedoch *Auch* am stärksten betont.

Der Schluss steht offensichtlich im Jambus, insofern wäre dieser Lesart Vorzug zubgeben. Um das zu beheben, muss eine Pause gelesen werden. Demnach hört sich die Wortfolge durchaus korrekt an. Im Ergebnis besteht ein scheinbarer Widerspruch, der durch steigende Betonung auf *voll-* aufgelöst wird. Ja das ist Trochäus, *Voll-er Er-folg* (Chorjambus —◡◡—). *Voll* klingt irgendwie *voller* als *groß* aber das Ergebnis ist dasselbe. Der Bruch könnte wahlweise durch Semikolon oder Auslassungszeichen verdeutlicht werden.

> Müsste es nicht heißen

> ¿? Wenn die Dreharbeiten auch noch so schwierig waren, ist der Film dennoch ein Erfolg.

Nee, das wäre wohl eine zeitliche Bestimmung, ohne dass die Zeitformen übereinstimmen. Als Konjunktion wäre es dahingehend nur Paradox: Um so beschwerlicher die Dreharbeiten, um so erfolgreicher das Ergebnis?

Das ist wohl teils lexikalisch bedingt. *so ... so ...* ist zwar historisch reichlich belegt, klingt aber veraltet, das scheidet schonmal aus.

*Auch wenn* ist soweit lexikalisiert, dass es elliptisch auftritt und zwar ebenso in anderen Sprachen (engl. *even so*).

Während "auch noch so schwierig*" häufig genug begegnet um noch verständlich zu sein, entbehrt es eigentlich jeder Logik und dürfte bezüglicher dieser postnominalen Wortstellung wohl eher vom Suffix PGem. *-hw abstammen, vgl. lat. *-que*, got. *-uh* beeinflusst sein, was im Deutschen ansonsten gar nicht belegt ist, und in der Bedeutung recht deutlich auf **h₂ewg-* zurückzuführen sein, insofern der Vergleich mit lat. *augeo*, *Augustus* usw., also eigentlich eine deverbale Ableitung. Mit Konjunktion hätte das recht wenig zu tun, so wenn VO als ursprünglich betrachtet werden kann. Da die weitere Herleitung unbekannt ist, kann ein Zusammenhang mit *h₂ew- (s. *Ohr*, *hören*) und *h₃ekʷ- (s. *Auge*, *äugen*) nicht ausgeschlossen werden. Als Diskurs Partikel wäre es einleuchtend: *Hömma, Schätzchen! Warn die Dreharbeiten noch so schwer, ist der Film denn och ein voller Erfolg geworden*. Bei entsprechender Zerlegung von *dennoch* dürfte die ungewisse Etymologie auch von *denken, Ding* usw. darunter fallen, vgl. präp. *dank* (dass dies erst im 19 Jh. aus *Dank [sei]* grammatikalisiert worden wäre ist angesichts identischer Wendung mit engl. *thank(s)* kaum glaubhaft).

---

Auf die Schriftsprache bezohen geht das natürlich überhaupt nicht, wenn es nicht im Buche steht. Und weil es nicht die eine authorativen Quelle gibt, lässt man es am besten ganz und bedient sich pejorativer Euphemismen wie *syntaktisch desintegriert*. Pausen sind ja so schwer zu verschriftlichen.